# Solidity - Remix IDE - How to test private functions?

Tags: function, testing, solidity, private

I am a beginner and I want to test private functions.

Is there a possibility on remix?

Thanks for any hint and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to test private methods, unless you create a getter for said method.

Private variables and methods have restricted (write) access to the current instance of the contract. Can't be accessed by inherited contracts, proxy or externally called.